# Given an array return true if can be splitted to two groups with same number of cells and same sum

Tags: java, recursion

Given an array, the method should return true if you can split it to two groups with the same number of cells and so the sum will be equal. **It needs to be done by recursion, and can't change the array values/order**, recursive private methods are allowed.

**Examples on random arrays:**

```
//{-3,5,12,14,-9,13} returns true
//{-3,5,-12,14,-9,13}; returns false,can find the sum but the groups are of 4 cells and 2 cells
//{-3,5,-12,14,-9}; returns false,cant split the array to two groups
```

Method name:

```
public static boolean equalSplit(int [] arr)
```

This is what I did:

```
 public static boolean equalSplit(int [] a)
    {
      return equalSplit(a,0,0,0,0,0);
     
    }
    
    
    private static boolean equalSplit(int [] a , int sum1 , int sum2 , int i,int c1,int c2)
    {
      
    if( i == a.length)
          
         return(sum1 == sum2 && c1 == c2);
       
      
    return
        equalSplit(a,sum1+a[i],sum2,i+1,c1 +1,c2) ||
        equalSplit(a,sum1,sum2+a[i] ,i+1,c1 ,c2+1);
     
    }
```

Do you see any problems here?

Comment: `can't change the array values/order` I'm *tempted* to add *for larger arrays, additional storage shall be small in comparison*. (Your guess why I'd rather not be caught doing so.)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. `any problems here?` You treat `sum1`/2, `c1`/2, base case as if they were independent. They are not, there are many futile operations.

Answer (score 2):

## Trivial Rejects

You are missing some easy checks which can rapidly yield a `false` result.  First, if `a.length` is not even, you cannot divide the array into two evenly sized groups.  Second, if \$\sum a_i\$ is not even, again you cannot divide the array into two groups which sum to the same value.

## Redundancy

If including `a[0]` in `sum1` can't find a solution, trying it in `sum2` is also guaranteed to fail, doubling the time required to produce the `false` result.

## Pruning

For `c1 == c2`, neither can be larger than `a.length/2`.  You can return `false` without ever exploring deeper in those subtrees.

## Code Formatting

Your spacing is inconsistent.  Eg) `int [] a , int sum1 , int sum2 , int i,int c1,int c2`   Use one space after commas, no spaces before them.

Indentation is inconsistent.

Use of blank lines is inconsistent.

There is no need for parentheses in your return statements.  `return(expr);` should be `return expr;`